# Promise.all() not resolving when running server - otherwise works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I've written a small tool that returns a promise after calling several other promises. This tool works great when I test it solo, it takes about 10 seconds in the example below. However, when I try to run it along with a http server instance it, takes in the order of several minutes to return, if at all!

I'm fairly sure I'm just misunderstanding something here, as I'm not extremely proficient in Node. If anyone can spot an issue, or suggest an alternative to using promises for handling asynchronous methods, please let me know!

Just to clarify, it's the **Promise.all** returned by the *traceRoute* function which is hanging. The sub-promises are all resolving as expected.

**Edit:** As suggested in the comments, I have also tried a recursive version with no call to Promise.all; same issue.

This is a **working** standalone version being called without any **http** server instance running:

```
const dns = require('dns');
const ping = require('net-ping');

var traceRoute = (host, ttl, interval, duration) => {

    var session = ping.createSession({
        ttl:ttl,
        timeout: 5000
    });

    var times = new Array(ttl);
    for (var i=0; i<ttl; i++){
        times[i] = {'ttl': null, 'ipv4': null, 'hostnames': [], 'times': []}
    };

    var feedCb = (error, target, ttl, sent, rcvd) => {
        var ms = rcvd - sent;
        if (error) {
            if (error instanceof ping.TimeExceededError) {
                times[ttl-1].ttl = ttl;
                times[ttl-1].ipv4 = error.source;
                times[ttl-1].times.push(ms)
            } else {
                console.log(target + ": " +
                error.toString () +
                " (ttl=" + ttl + " ms=" + ms +")");
            }
        } else {
            console.log(target + ": " +
            target + " (ttl=" + ttl + " ms=" + ms +")");
        }
    }

    var proms = new Array();
    var complete = 0

    while(complete < duration){
        proms.push(
            new Promise((res, rej) => {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    session.traceRoute(
                        host,
                        { maxHopTimeouts: 5 },
                        feedCb,
                        function(e,t){
                            console.log('traceroute done: resolving promise')
                            res();  // resolve inner promise
                        }
                    );
                }, complete);
            })
        )
        complete += interval;
    }

    return Promise.all(proms)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('resolving traceroute');
        return times.filter((t)=> t.ttl != null);
    });
}


traceRoute('195.146.144.8', 20, 500, 5000)
.then( (times) => console.log(times) )
```

Below, is the same logic being called from inside the server instance, this is **not working** as it should. See the inline comment for where exactly it hangs.

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({server: server, path: "/wss"});
const dns = require('dns');
const ping = require('net-ping');

var traceRoute = (host, ttl, interval, duration) => {

    var session = ping.createSession({
        ttl:ttl,
        timeout: 5000
    });

    var times = new Array(ttl);
    for (var i=0; i<ttl; i++){
        times[i] = {'ttl': null, 'ipv4': null, 'hostnames': [], 'times': []}
    };

    var feedCb = (error, target, ttl, sent, rcvd) => {
        var ms = rcvd - sent;
        if (error) {
            if (error instanceof ping.TimeExceededError) {
                times[ttl-1].ttl = ttl;
                times[ttl-1].ipv4 = error.source;
                times[ttl-1].times.push(ms)
            } else {
                console.log(target + ": " + 
                error.toString () + " (ttl=" + ttl + " ms=" + ms +")");
            }
        } else {
            console.log(target + ": " + target + 
            " (ttl=" + ttl + " ms=" + ms +")");
        }
    }

    var proms = new Array();
    var complete = 0

    while(complete < duration){
        proms.push(
            new Promise((res, rej) => {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    session.traceRoute(
                        host,
                        { maxHopTimeouts: 5 },
                        feedCb,
                        function(e,t){
                            console.log('traceroute done: resolving promise')
                            res();  // resolve inner promise
                        }
                    );
                }, complete);
            })
        )
        complete += interval;
    }

    console.log('Promise all:', proms);

    // #####################
    // Hangs on this promise
    // i.e. console.log('resolving traceroute') is not called for several minutes.
    // #####################
    return Promise.all(proms)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('resolving traceroute')
        return times.filter((t)=> t.ttl != null)
    });
}

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {

    traceRoute('195.146.144.8', 20, 500, 5000)
    .then((data) => ws.send(data));

});

app.use('/tools/static', express.static('./public/static'));
app.use('/tools/templates', express.static('./public/templates'));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/templates/index.html');
});

server.listen(8081);
```

**Note:** I have tried calling it before the `server.listen`, after `server.listen`, from inside `wss.on('connection', ...`. None of which makes a difference. Calling it anywhere, while the server is listening, causes it to behave in a non-deterministic manner.

Comment: I take it you get 10 x **traceroute done: resolving promise** - have you tried, for the sake of debugging, adding a `.catch` on the `Promise.all`?

Comment: I haven't actually. I'll give it a look over the next few days. And yes, 10x traceroute to measure jitter... Cheers.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the tip, but it's not throwing any errors on any of the promises. This is a time issue. It runs okay with the server, but takes about 3 minutes on average, as opposed to 10 seconds. I'm inclined to think it's something to do with how Node HTTP handles sockets, but I'm still investigating this...

Comment: I am not sure why exactly it isn't working, but this looks like it might better be done with a recursive function than creating an array of promises. Something like `var trace = //whats in your set timeout`, then in the `trace` function have a set time out to call itself upon completion if `complete < duration`. Will write out better what I am thinking later if you still need help.

Comment: @JoeLissner thanks Joe, I'm afraid I've already tried recursion. I moved to Promise.all in the hope that it'd be handled differently, or perhaps trigger a low-level event, but it's the same issue. Can't help but feel it's the 'http' module causing an issue with promises in general.

Comment: @RichardDunn I don't think there are such issues with http module interfering with Promise.all(). I don't have much proof on this, but writing my own framework strongly relying on Promises there is a unit test assessing its performance triggering several hundred HTTP requests at once involving Promise.all() to wait for all requests to complete. This test is repeated hundreds of times and succeeds within 10s. Your code is pretty complex and dependent to actually locate the issue that simply.

Comment: Tried setting up your code in c9.io and inspect it more thoroughly. However, after some restarts the ping.createSession() fails with Operation not permitted ... and I can't get it back to running again. Looks like there is something eating up resources. Maybe it's not related, but that test code is pretty complex for reproducing anything.

Comment: um, your code works for me. You *do* trigger the function to execute by starting a WS connection? whats your node version?

Comment: @Lux Yes. I've tried several versions.

Comment: @Lux What OS are you using?

Comment: Mac OS 10.11.6, node 8.2.1. Can you specify your OS and node version?

Comment: Debian 9.1, Fedora Server 26, Windows 10 (latest). v4.8.4, v6.11.2, v8.2.1.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not going to accept this answer as it's only a workaround; it was just too long to put in the comments...

None of the promises, including the Promise.all, are throwing exceptions. However, Node *seems* to be parking the call to Promise.all. I accidentally discovered that if I keep a timeout loop running while waiting for the promise.all to resolve, then it will in fact resolve as and when expected.

I'd love if someone could explain exactly what is happening here as I don't really understand.

```
var holdDoor = true
var ps = () => {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('status:', proms);
        if (holdDoor) ps();
    }, 500);
}
ps();

return Promise.all(proms)
.then(() => {
    holdDoor = false
    console.log('Resolving all!')
    return times.filter((t)=> t.ttl != null)
});
```

Comment: Sorry about my previous answer. I'm now caught up with you and getting the same behavior. Very strange indeed!

Comment: No worries, I was just about to comment asking for more details about your node version, os, etc. But no need... It has returned ok for me as well, just one or twice, but vast majority of the time it hangs. :/

Comment: You know, you don't need a setTimeout or setInterval on the proms. Just sending another websocket connection to the server will work too. It's as though the event loop doesn't know it has something to do unless a timer or IO poll happens.

Comment: I think we're getting somewhere. This is is from raw-socket, net-pings, only dependency: https://github.com/stephenwvickers/node-raw-socket#keeping-the-nodejs-event-loop-alive

Comment: I give up! :) I suspect it's an issue with how raw-socket is interacting with the event loop. The most elegant workaround I found is to wrap your resolve call in a setImmediate.

Comment: Thanks, I've been helping track a couple of bugs on raw-socket but never noticed the stuff about the event loop! I'll try asking the author and see if he'll weigh in on this...

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working perfectly fine!

To reproduce this I've created a `Dockerfile` with a working version. You can find it in [this git repository](https://github.com/luxferresum/promise-all-problem), or you can pull it with `docker pull luxferresum/promise-all-problem`.

You can run the docker image with `docker run -ti -p 8081:8081 luxferresum/promise-all-problem`. This will expose the webserver on `localhost:8081`.

You can also just run the `problematic.js` with `node problematic.js` and then opening `localhost:8081` in the web browser.

The web socket will be opened by `const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081/wss');` which then triggers the code to run.

Its just very important to actually open the web socket, without that the code will not run.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test this on your Mac, it does give some insight into the nature of the issue. Unfortunately, however, my servers do not run a Macintosh OS, thus the issue persists.

Comment: I've run it in docker, this means on a standarized linux environment. Can you verify that the docker image does not work for you?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just not interested in setting up a docker environment to work around this bug. I'm not sure if I made it clear in the question, answer, or comments, but I'm looking to understand this bug, not sweep it under the carpet. This is purely educational, I have long moved past this being a blocker for my work.

Comment: then that would be helpful. If the docker container works this would show that its a problem in your local environment. If not, its either your kernel or something in your network. And its interesting, because I was also able to run this code working under windows 10.

Comment: I was taking another look at this bug and re-read your answer just now, I didn't notice before but your statement that docker provides a "standarized linux environment" is wrong. This is not how containers work, just an FYI...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest replacing the trace route with something else, like a DNS lookup, and see of the issue remains.  At this point you cannot be sure it relates to raw-socket, since that uses libuv handles directly and does not effect other parts of the Node.js event loop.

Comment: True. I'll verify this sometime today, hopefully. I'll also try add a simplified all-in-one example code snippet. Cheers.